# Why is Node.js executing in this manner?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose, async.js

I have a Node.js application that I am using to migrate records from MySql to MongoDB.  I am using Mongoose and async.js, to do this and I have noticed some behavior that I do not understand.  If I have the following Coffeescript code ([javascript here](http://pastebin.com/cAKxEy29)):

```
           # users is a collection of about 70k records
async.each users, ((user, callback) =>
    # console.log "saving user: #{user.id} of #{users[users.length-1].id}"
    model = new User
        id: user.id
        name:
            first: user.fname
            last: user.lname
    model.save (err) ->
        console.log "saving user: #{user.id}"
        model = null
        callback(err)
), (err) ->
    users = null
    callback(err)
```

The callback for `model.save` is never reached and my Node process will slowly creep up to 1.5gb.  If I check my mongodb instance, I can see that after all 70k items in the `users` collection have been processed, records will begin saving to mongodb, but they stop at around 41k.

I've noticed that if I switch from [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) to [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries), the call back for `model.save` is reached for each record and the migration completes successfully.

I'm assuming that for some reason, Node is running every iteration of the async.each against every item in the `users` collection before it executes the callback for `model.save`, which is causing a memory issue, but I don't understand why this is.  Can anyone tell me why Node would be doing this, and why switching to `async.eachSeries` fixes this problem?

Comment: Maybe the mongodb driver is experiencing concurrency issues, have you tried using [`async.queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency) instead of `each`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neil has done a great job of providing a solution, but I just wanted to touch on your question:

> Can anyone tell me why Node would be doing this, and why switching to async.eachSeries fixes this problem?

If you look at the details to `async.each` vs `async.eachSeries`, you may notice that the documentation for `async.each` states:

> Applies the function iterator to each item in arr, in parallel

However, `async.eachSeries` states:

> The same as each, only iterator is applied to each item in arr in series. The next iterator is only called once the current one has completed. This means the iterator functions will complete in order.

In detail, if we look at the code you'll see that the code for `each` ends up calling the native `forEach` function on the array itself, and each element calls the iterator ([link to source](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/2f8680c6bd96a0ba7b38f052d200f6364a02de69/lib/async.js#L124-L126)):

```
_each(arr, function (x) {
    iterator(x, only_once(done) );
});
```

which calls:

```
var _each = function (arr, iterator) {
    if (arr.forEach) {
        return arr.forEach(iterator);
    }
```

However, each call to your iterator function ends up calling `model.save`.  This Mongoose function (among other things) ends up performing I/O to save your data to the database.  If you were to trace the code path, you'd see that it ends up in a function which calls `process.nextTick` ([link to source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/566e746c2f7fce796ce2a8d2b5dc42f74080e872/lib/document.js#L951)).

Node's [`process.nextTick`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) function is typically used in situations such as this (I/O), and will process the callback once the flow of execution has ended.  In this situation, each callback will only be called once the forEach loop has completed.  (This was purposeful, and meant to not block any code execution.)

So to sum up:

When using `async.each`, the code you have above will run through all your users, queuing up the saves, but only begin to process them once the code has completed iterating over all the users.

When using `async.eachSeries`, the code you have above will process each user one at a time, and only process the next user once the save has completed -- when the eachSeries callback has been called.

Comment: Wonderful, clear answer.  Thanks for breaking it down!

Answer (score 1):

Well there certainly is a problem with throwing the kitchen sink at your process. It is doing essentially what you ask it to and therefore trying to asynchronously "spin up" all of these "save" operations at once. The basic reality is you only have so many connections to MongoDB that you can deal with so there is going to be a bottleneck somewhere when you do this.

A better approach than doing this in "series" if you don't actually need the operations to complete in an explicit order would be to use a "limit" on the amount of operations you are queuing up. There is [`async.eachLimit()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) to do exactly this.

The calling convention seems a bit odd here, so this seems a bit cleaner, to me at least:

```
async.eachLimit(users,500,function(user,callback){
    var model = new Model({
        id: user.id,
        name: {
            first: user.fname,
            last: user.lname
        }
    });
    model.save(function(err, model) {
        console.log("saving user: " + model.id);
        callback(err);
    });
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("there was a problem");
    } else {
        console.log("all successful");
    }
});
```

Or as basic translated coffeescript:

```
async.eachLimit users, 500, ((user, callback) ->
  model = new Model(
    id: user.id
    name:
      first: user.fname
      last: user.lname
  )
  model.save (err, model) ->
    console.log "saving user: " + model.id
    callback err
    return

  return
), (err) ->
  if err
    console.log "there was a problem"
  else
    console.log "all successful"
  return
```

And the final callback will then process after all callbacks are returned, but you are "throttling" what you are throwing at mongoose and indeed MongoDB.

You also might want to look into the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) of MongoDB unless you explicitly **need** to use the "validation" functions or others from your model. This essentially allows you to send a "batch" of inserts at once, rather than sending each document to the database "one at a time".

Contrived example here, using eachSeries but the actual "writes" are grouped:

```
var async = require("async"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var tenSchema = new Schema({
  value: Number
});

var Ten = mongoose.model( "Ten", tenSchema, "ten" );

var ten = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var pos = 0;

mongoose.connection.on("open",function(err,conn) {

  var bulk = Ten.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

  async.eachSeries(ten,function(item,callback) {

    bulk.insert({ "value": item });
    pos++;

    if ( pos % 2 == 0 ) {
      bulk.execute(function(err,res) {
        pos = 0;
        bulk = Ten.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        callback(err);
      });
    } else {
      callback();
    }

  },function(err) {

    if (err)
      throw err;

    if ( pos != 0 ) {
      bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
        console.log("done");
      });
    } else {
      console.log("done");
    }

  });

});
```

So in your case just "up" the value to count for the modulo, say to 500 and that will process the array but only write to the database once every 500 items.

The only thing to be aware of is this is a native driver function and not using the mongoose API. So you need to be careful ( in the case of a migrations script or similar ) to make sure the current connection is established before referencing these methods. The contrived way here is looking for "open", but basically you just want to be sure, by other means normally.

You could get fancier with queues of parallel "bulk writes", but the general performance should be better than with any other method without going to further lengths.

Comment: Superb answer, thank you so much!  Wish I could accept both your and dylant's answers.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Fair enough. I was mainly about providing alternates to simply processing intensive I/O in series. But the other is a fair explanation how `.each()` is just queuing up the work without a limit on it. So `.eachSeries()` will avoid that, `.eachLimit()` reduces the concurrent operations to a working number, and the batch updates reduce the I/O overhead.